# JQuery to get an Array of Attributes returned

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

So I am trying with this Script to get back an Array of Attributes. But I can't get it to work properly.

```
function synch(){
    var look=$("#reviernummer").val();
    var secure=$('.sorted').each(function() {
        return (this.attr("tag");
        });
    //alert(look);
    //alert(secure[5]);
    //alert(secure.length);
    $("option").filter(".sorted"&!"#title" == look).css("display", "none");
};
```

As you can see i am loading it from an SQL Table so i want it to get the tag value of all the Entries in the dropdown and after I get that i want to filter them and all the ones who don't match get hidden. The `<select>` should now only display the Elements i want.

```
<select class="required" id="revierbereich" style="width:240px;" name="verhaltenscode_neu" >
    <?php $selected = $arrayAktuellerDatensatz['verhaltenscode_neu'];?>
    <option selected ="selected" value="<?php echo $selected; ?>"><?php echo $selected; ?></option>
    <?php loadselect_neu('helpbrutstatus', 'Fischereibuchzahl', 'Fischereibuchzahl', $_Get["verhaltenscode"]);?>
</select><br />




<?php
function loadselect_neu($tblname, $value, $caption, $VC){
    if ($tblname == 'helpbrutstatus'){

        $query = "SELECT * FROM helpbrutstatus " ;

        $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
            $fieldvalue = $row['Brutstatus'];
            $status = $row['Fischereibuchzahl'];
            $fieldcaption = $row['Brutstatus']; ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $fieldvalue;?>" title="<?php echo $status;?>" tag="<?php echo $status;?>" class="sorted"><?php echo $status."&nbsp;|&nbsp;".$fieldcaption."&nbsp;|&nbsp;".$VC ?></option> <?php
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create an array from properties of your HTML elements, use `map()`. Also note that creating your own non-standard attributes is invalid HTML. If you want to store custom data with an element, use a `data-*` attribute. Try this:

```
var secure = $('.sorted').map(function() {
    return $(this).data("tag");
}).get();
```

```php
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    // code here... ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $fieldvalue;?>" title="<?php echo $status;?>" data-tag="<?php echo $status;?>" class="sorted">
        <?php echo $status."&nbsp;|&nbsp;".$fieldcaption."&nbsp;|&nbsp;".$VC ?>
    </option> 
<?php }
```